# Can Zangetsu get through small gaps?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

Doing my Zangetsu playthrough and I found that he can reach most places right from the start... except small gaps like this.

[image: small gap to a HP upgrade]

**Can Zangetsu get through gaps like this?** I want to get that HP upgrade.